# Web API: Error when calling responseTask.Wait() after GetAsync in ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I am following a Web API tutorial, everything has been fine, but I am getting an 'SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' exception in the responseTask.Wait() call.

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> students = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64189/api/");
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("student");
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<StudentViewModel>>();
                readTask.Wait();

                students = readTask.Result;
            }
            else 
            {
                students = Enumerable.Empty<StudentViewModel>();

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
        return View(students);
    }
}
```

I already add a  *ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = **SecurityProtocolType.Tls1*****2** but it didn't solve anything.

I tested the API itself https://localhost:12345/api/student and t**he service is Ok**. It's in the responseTask.Wait method where it fails.

Comment: Why use `.Wait()` and `.Result` instead of just using `async` and `await`?  If you switch to that, does the problem persist?

Comment: I agree with David. make the whole action concurrent. Dont use this function .Wait() on task. I dont think think this is needed .Result. It is a server side error. Something related to networking, there isnt enough information to help us find the problem why SocketException is thrown. Try to use postman to make a request to this url: http://localhost:64189/api/student

Comment: Yes I confirm that the request to localhost:64189/api/student is Ok.

Comment: Hi @PabloZegarra, your url is not correct. It should be  `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:64189/api/");` https instead of http.